# My code isn't using assembly for "register date", is there an assembly i'm not using? (using datepicker)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I'm using Asp.Net MVC pages etc. and I'm having trouble with using datepicker (found in Razor End). To clarify, I don't understand exactly how this works, so my apologies if I get this wrong, but i've been searching for hours and hours for a datepicker that can be used on ASP.NET programs, with not much luck, so I'd definitely appreciate the help!

```
@page
@model IndexModel

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="RegisterDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <div class='input-group date' id='datepicker'>
            <input asp-for="RegisterDate" type="text" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm")" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <span asp-validation-for="RegisterDate" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    @section Scripts
    {
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $('#datepicker').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    }
```

[Razor Page Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz6jZ.png)

[Razor Page Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2qXW.png)

Code Behind:

```
[...]
  public class IndexModel : PageModel

    {
        #region BindProperty
        [BindProperty] public string firstName { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public string lastName { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public string emailAddress { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public string ticketNumber { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public string ticketTitle { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public string ticketDescription { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public string ticketID { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public string birthdate { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public string ageValue { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public DateTime? RegisterDate { get; set; }
        #endregion
[...]
```

[Previous Code Behind - Image 1 - (If needed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zhd7.png)

[Current Code Behind - Image 2 - (if needed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI9Rf.png)

Comment: Hi @LukeMurray2002,you can see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code like below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="RegisterDate" class="control-label"></label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker" data-target-input="nearest">
        <input class="form-control datetimepicker-input" asp-for="RegisterDate" type="text" data-target="#datetimepicker" />
        <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span asp-validation-for="RegisterDate" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
    @section Scripts{
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm',
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
```

Test result:

[image]

***Update***

Your IndexModel should like following:

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public DateTime? RegisterDate { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {         
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to clear some things up, but I am still getting the same error, except for "RegisterDate" instead. ("Index model does not contain a definition for RegisterDate") - I assume this is to do with binding the property to my code-behind, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do there.

Comment: If so, can you share your model and pagemodel?

Comment: I've updated my post to add my current code. I have tried playing with the code behind (and yes, my first problem was the BindProperty function) and the first issue has been solved, however now I am receiving an error "Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'." (I have my code set to run in IIS Express) - what could cause this? I have never had this error before and would have to assume it was caused by the new code.

Comment: This problem is not caused by the new code. You can try to delete the new code and run it. For this problem,you can try running vs as admin before opening and running project.and next to the Green start arrow, you have a down arrow click it and select "IIS EXPRESS". Then press the start arrow once again to run your application.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much for your brilliant brain, Yinqui!